# How to accept a Guid as an input type in Blazor Server

Tags: c#, html, web-component, blazor-server-side

I have an app in which im trying to create a record of the type:

```
public class ObfuscatingTradeDatum
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ProviderName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ClientNameAsAppearsOnTradeData { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ClientCode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Guid ProviderDynamicsId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Guid TraderDynamicsId { get; set; }
}
```

My blazor page is of the form:

```
<EditForm Model="@ObfuscatingTradeData" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
<DataAnnotationsValidator />
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Provider Name:</label>
    <div>
        <InputText @bind-Value="@ObfuscatingTradeData.ProviderName" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => ObfuscatingTradeData.ProviderName)" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group ">
    <div>
        <label>Client Name:</label>
        <div>
            <InputText @bind-Value="@ObfuscatingTradeData.ClientNameAsAppearsOnTradeData" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => ObfuscatingTradeData.ClientNameAsAppearsOnTradeData)" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group ">
    <div>
        <label>Client Code:</label>
        <div>
            <InputText @bind-Value="@ObfuscatingTradeData.ClientCode" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => ObfuscatingTradeData.ClientCode)" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group ">
    <div>
        <label>Provider Dynamics ID:</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" @bind="@ObfuscatingTradeData.ProviderDynamicsId" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => ObfuscatingTradeData.ProviderDynamicsId)" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group ">
    <div>
        <label>Trader Dynamics ID:</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" @bind="@ObfuscatingTradeData.TraderDynamicsId" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => ObfuscatingTradeData.TraderDynamicsId)" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">@ButtonText</button>
```

```
@code {
    public ObfuscatingTradeDatum ObfuscatingTradeData = new ObfuscatingTradeDatum();
    [Parameter] public string ButtonText { get; set; } = "Save";
    private void HandleValidSubmit() => Service.InsertObfuscatingTradeDatum(ObfuscatingTradeData);
}
```

My issues occur on this line:

```
<input @bind="@ObfuscatingTradeData.TraderDynamicsId" />
```

What i would like is to use an input component that accepts Guids, this way I can get the built in validaiton that comes for free. However the following code throws the error "The type 'System.Guid' is not a supported numeric type.":

```
<InputNumber @bind-Value="@ObfuscatingTradeData.TraderDynamicsId" />
```

This error makes sense, however from the search i have done I am not sure how to pass a guid as input. Any help would be greatly aprreciated.

Many Thanks,

Comment: Use `inputText` !

Comment: This produces a complilation error of "Cannot convert from System.Guid to string"

Comment: did you try the solution down?

Comment: Unfortunately the below solution causes further issues with Entity Framework. This method feels a little "Hacky" to me and it feels like there should be a more supported solution to my problem

Comment: It can not be, I tested!,  and the it works fine, I think that you have another problem, see the solution down in `BlazorFiddle`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can do something like this:

```
public class ObfuscatingTradeDatum
{
  //....
  public string ProviderDynamicsIdAsString { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public Guid ProviderDynamicsId
  {
    get { return Guid.TryParse(ProviderDynamicsIdAsString, out Guid g) ? g : default; }
    set { ProviderDynamicsIdAsString = Convert.ToString(value); }
  }
  public string TraderDynamicsIdAsString { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public Guid TraderDynamicsId
  {
    get { return Guid.TryParse(TraderDynamicsIdAsString, out Guid g) ? g : default; }
    set { TraderDynamicsIdAsString = Convert.ToString(value); }
  }
}
```

Then:

```
<InputText id="name" @bind-Value="ObfuscatingTradeData.TraderDynamicsIdAsString " />
<span>@ObfuscatingTradeData.TraderDynamicsId.ToString()</span>
```

You can see the example in [BlazorFiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/say814dv)